# Sivlerstripe 3 Gridfield Extensions - Inline editing for grid with uploadfield

Tags: silverstripe

I've got a Dataobject with a textfield and an uploadfield. I want to use the inline editing functionality from the Silverstripe Gridfield Extensions but it seams that I'm doing something wrong or the extension is not made for uploadfields.

That's what I tried sofar

```
...
    'Visual' => function($record, $column, $grid) {
        return new UploadField($column);
    }
```

or

```
...
    'Visual' => array(
        'title' => 'Bild',
        'field' => 'UploadField'
    )
```

can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the gridfieldextensions module by ajshort?

I am pretty sure the UploadField will not work within an inline edit GridField.
Unfortunately the UploadField is very complex in its layout, and the styles for it are a bit fragile, so it will most likely break (at least the style) if you nest it within something like a GridField table.

Also the UploadField is capable of handling unsaved records, but I don't think the GridField Inline Editing module is built in a way that UploadField would understand, so even if you get the style and javascript of the UploadField to work, uploading will still only work after saving a record.

---

a better alternative would probably be to use the GridFieldBulkEditingTools module.
I have never used it, but it looks promising. Get it on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/colymba/gridfield-bulk-editing-tools) or [GitHub](https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools)

Comment: I'm already using this but only for bulk-deleting. But you'r right. That should solve my problem.